# is there way to customize timestamp in AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to customize timestamp in AJAX

currently I have running code like this, this is working. but time stamp is too long with h-M-s, so I want to show only Y-M. If You have any idea to solve this ,

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  MyrefereesAdds();
});

function MyrefereesAdds() {
  $("#Referees").empty();
  $.ajax({
      url: 'My_Ref_adds',
      type: 'GET',
      datatype: 'html',
      data: {
        ContactNo: '{{ Auth::user()->RefCode }}'
      },
    })
    .done(function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(index, val) {

        var Time = = val.created_at; // I think we can do some this in here....

        $('#Referees').append('<tr>')
        $('#Referees').append('<td scope="row">' + val.RefId + '</td>')
        $('#Referees').append('<td>' + val.ViewCategory + '</td>')
        $('#Referees').append('<td>' + val.created_at + '</td>')
        $('#Referees').append('<td>' + val.Status + '</td>')
        $('#Referees').append('</tr>')
      });
    })
    .fail(function() {
      alert("fail");
      console.log("error");
    })
}
```

Comment: Where in the code you posted do yo have anything with timestamps? You can format your `val.created_at` if you want.

Comment: You can do it easily from controller, then why you need ajax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var Time = new Date(val.created_at).getFullYear() + '-' + ('0' + (new Date(val.created_at).getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use dayjs library to format your date.
Load the library and you can

```
dayjs(val.created_at).format('YYYY-M')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do `Y-M` useing

```
 +  val.created_at.getUTCFullYear() + "/" +
    ("0" + (val.created_at.getUTCMonth()+1)).slice(-2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
let date = new Date(val.created_a)
$('#Referees').append('<td>' + tdate.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '</td>')
```